# Serializing inbuilt classes in Flutter and Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

It is straightforward to serialize a custom Dart class to and from JSON by annotating it with `@JsonSerializable()`, adding the `fromJson` and `toJson` methods, and then running the code generation utility.

What is the correct to serialize Dart's **Map** and **LinkedList** classes from the *dart:core* and *dart:collection* packages respectively? These are not annotated with `@JsonSerializable()`, and do not include the `fromJson` and `toJson` methods.

If I try to serialize a LinkedList, using:

```
String s = jsonEncode(myLinkedList);
```

the following error is thrown:

```
JsonUnsupportedObjectError (Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'LinkedList<MyClass>')
```

The definition of `myLinkedList` is:

```
final myLinkedList = LinkedList<myEntryItem>();
```

where `myEntryItem` is annotated with `@JsonSerializable`

Thanks

Comment: They work just like that. Personally I had't even heard of the `@JsonSerializable()` annotation. I suppose it's from the json_serializable package but that's not the default way.

Comment: Could you show how you then serialize these built in classes? Have edited the question to show how I am serializing. Thanks very much

Comment: It seems `LinkedList` doesn't work, but after converting it to a normal list it should work (at least if the LinkedListEntry class has a `toJson()` method) so like `jsonEncode(myLinkedList.toList());`. `Map` should already work just like that

Comment: Thanks - but the insertion order is important - will that not be lost by converting to a regular `List` and then back to `LinkedList` ?

Comment: @user1052610 Converting a `LinkedList` to a `List` and back would preserve the order of the elements.  Neither one keeps track of *insertion* order.

Comment: It's easy to convert `LinkedList` to `List` and then then serialize the list. But after deserializing the list, how do you convert it back into a LinkedList? Doing so manually be traversing on a very large list on startup could be very slow.

Comment: @user1052610 Possibly, but it'd be a constant-factor cost for what ultimately would be O(n) anyway.  You'd still need to traverse the large list anyway for serialization/deserialization.  JSON doesn't have linked lists; ultimately you will need to use an array-like object (`List`).  There's no way around that unless you want to write your own JSON decoder that builds `LinkedList` objects from JSON lists.